# How to pass arguments to QueryDicts and consecutively pass it to a django form to be used inside it

Tags: python, django

**Description:**
I'm playing with django forms to fill in `Completed_Exercise` Model instances for those users that have completed successfully a determined exercise by use of `ModelForm` class, but since a `Completed_ExerciseForm` has three fields, two of which correspond to ForeignKey fields, I don't need to render them on template but the score one (hilariously user can do self-qualification), so the thing is I decided to pass both of them as arguments to `ModelForm` instance through a `request.GET` copy.

I googled for an hour and tried & corrected stuff... but even so I'm making the same mistake, as far as I know this can be done likewise by passing them as kwargs to the form, but its not the intended way. Any help is really appreciated.

**Result:**
I cant access to QueryDict from inside of the form

**Models:**

```
class Completed_Exercise(models.Model):

    possible_scores = list(zip(range(1,8), range(1,8)))
    exercise = models.OneToOneField(Exercise, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=possible_scores)
    student = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Student', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='completed_exercises')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#Student belongs to other django app, despite its placed alongside the first one. 
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student")
    pui = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, default='')
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**View:**

```
def exercise_detail_view(request,pk):
    
    form = Completed_ExerciseForm()
    exercise = get_object_or_404(Exercise, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            copy = request.GET.copy()
            
            copy['student'] = request.user.student
            copy['exercise'] = get_object_or_404(Exercise, pk=pk)
            form = Completed_ExerciseForm(copy)
            print(copy)
            print('you are registered...glad am i')
        else:
            return redirect('login')

        if request.user.student.completed_exercises.filter(pk=pk).exists():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'You are done with that exercise already')
            print('exercise_completed!!!')
            return redirect('exercise/' + str(pk))

        elif form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            print('saved the holy form')
            return redirect(request.META['HTTP-REFERER'])
   
    
    context = { 'exercise':exercise, 'form':form }
    return render(request, 'training/exercise.html',context=context)
```

**Form:**

```
class Completed_ExerciseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.qQ = args[0]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Completed_Exercise.objects.create(student = self.qQ['student'], exercise = self.qQ['exercise'], points = self.points)

    class Meta:
        model = Completed_Exercise
        fields = ['points']
```

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpCqx.png)

I think this is enough for an answer, if not be the case please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `ModelForm` you can provide the `initial` keyword argument which is a dict of field names for keys and values which the form will be loaded with. I also wouldn't override `save()` like that.

So in your case, to define those FK fields with those values, you'd do something like;

```
class Completed_ExerciseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Completed_Exercise
        fields = [
            'points',
            'student',
            'exercise'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'student': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'exercise': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

def exercise_detail_view(request,pk):
    
    form = Completed_ExerciseForm()
    exercise = get_object_or_404(Exercise, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            initial = {}
            initial['student'] = request.user.student
            initial['exercise'] = get_object_or_404(Exercise, pk=pk)
            form = Completed_ExerciseForm(initial=initial)
            print(initial)
            print('you are registered...glad am i')
        else:
            return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @markwalker, but the reason i do this is just for experimenting and its on a whim also. do you know why i cant access to the form QueryDict object from inside it?

Comment: You'd have to have a look at what the args actually are before you attempt to take an index position from them like you do there. If you really want to do that, you'd be better defining your method signature explicitly like `def __init__(self, qQ, *args, **kwargs):`